# Same height for two flexboxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Update: Thanks all for your kind comments. I have taken up isherwood's advice to use flexbox and pytth's comments on naming of id/ class.

Now, I have this but the height of the two flexboxes are not the same. What am I doing wrong? I have tried setting min-height, and height: 100% to no avail.

[image]

Here's my updated HTML:

```
<section class="featured movie">
    <!--featured movie-->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content-1">
                <!--image-->
                <img src="images/edge of tomorrow.jpg.png" alt="Edge of Tomorrow" href="featured.html" class="featured-banner">
            </div>
            <!--headings-->
            <div class="content-2">
                <h1>Edge of Tomorrow</h1>
                <h2>Rating: 4/5</h2>
                <h3>It leaves you on the edge, wishing for a tomorrow.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And my updated CSS:

```
    @media(min-width:768px) {
    .container {
        display: flex; /*puts the 2 contents side by side*/ 
        margin: auto; 
        justify-content: center;
        width: 70%; 
        min-height: 100%;
        padding-top: 20px; 
    }
}

.content-1 {
    flex: 1 ;
    min-height: 0%; 
    height: 100%; 
}

.content-2 {
    background-color: grey; 
    flex: 1;
}
```

Would appreciate any advice/ suggestions. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I suggest removing floats from your lexicon. They're rarely useful except to wrap text around images. Use flexbox or CSS grid instead.

Comment: Judging by your class names you're using (or creating) a layout system. Please tell us about that in your question (and tags). It seems relevant.

Comment: If flexbox or grid solutions appeal to you, let us know that as well. Some of us are reluctant to offer solutions that differ dramatically from your approach. Ideally you'll try it yourself first and update your question.

Comment: is the image supposed to shrink or the container to expand ?

Comment: Just drive by saying: Because of the high level of selector specificity, you should not be styling elements using `ids`

Comment: grid and flex can be quiet buggy resizing image, but your first thought about table can be applied via display: here is a possible  example https://jsfiddle.net/wbq47uLv/

Answer (score 0):

What isherwood has said but with some context. Try stay away from id's unless you want to specifically target something. Otherwise Class is better. In terms of rows and columns, unless you are using a front end framework like bootstrap, your better off just using your own stuff.

Have a look into display flex, its quite an indepth thing and works for most situations

```
 <section class="featured-movie">
   <!--featured movie-->
   <!--image-->
   <div class="featured-image">
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Edge of Tomorrow" href="featured.html" class="featured-banner">
     </div>
   <!--headings-->
   <div class="featured-content">
     <h1>Edge of Tomorrow</h1>
     <h2>Rating: 4/5</h2>
     <h3>It leaves you on the edge, wishing for a tomorrow.</h3>
   </div>
</section>
```

```
/*==FEATURED SECTION===*/ 

/*Align featured movie & texts to middle of page*/ 
.featured-movie {
    width: 70%; /*so that there is 15% space left and right*/ 
    margin-left: 15%; 
    margin-right: 15%; 
    padding-top: 20px; 
    display: flex;
    
}

/*====FEATURED IMAGE===*/ 
.featured-banner {
    min-width: 320px; 
    width: 70%; /*banner to occupy 70% of space within the 70%*/ 
    float: left; 
}

/*featured section for text*/ 
.featured-content {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center; 
    width: 30%; 
    background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to all:

After researching more I have used a grid CSS layout which works perfectly. Thanks all for your kind comments and guidance! :-)